# Is it possible to add multiple vectors together that have the same magnitude and angle separating them?

Tags: classical-mechanics, vectors

Is there a way to find the sum of 4 vectors that are 45 degrees apart from one another and all have the same magnitude?

Comment: Like with any set of vectors, you just add them component-wise. Is there a specific context to the question?

Comment: This is very similar to your [recent closed question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/618956).

Comment: Vector spaces are defined to be closed under addition, so the sum of 4 vectors does necessarily exist.

Comment: draw a diagram and the answer will be obvious (and, more generally, always draw a diagram and think about it before posting physics or maths questions on the web).

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I like you to do:

1. Take the first two vectors $\vec v_1$, and $\vec v_2$ and figure out how you add these two, $\vec v_{12} = \vec v_1+\vec v_2$.
2. Add a third vector to the resulting vector of step 1. Thus, again, we are only considering two vectors, $\vec v_{123} = \vec v_{12}+\vec v_3$.
3. Add the last vector.